# In a clique consensus private network, what happens when a sealer (signer) stops mining

Tags: private-blockchain, clique

I create a private network with two sealers running on two separate nodes. I found that if one node stops signing by miner.stop(), the other one start to wait for it and stoped signing blocks too. The info log is like

```
INFO [11-22|14:38:26.031] Signed recently, must wait for others
```

What happens when a sealer (signer) stops mining if there are several sealers in a network.

Answer (score 4):

> Clique requires int(N/2+1) sealers (where N is the number of sealers
>   defined in the genesis file — in extraData field) to be online in
>   order to run.
>
> thx to Ivica Aracic for pointing out that clique PoA DOES WORK with a
>   single node. For any reason I missed that and I apologize for the
>   confusion. With a single node, we just need (A) create genesis file
>   with only one sealer (only 1 address in extraData ) (B) create an
>   account (C) init geth (D) run geth, unlock account and mine. No
>   bootnode is required then.

source - https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8

Looks like this is defined by the `SIGNER_LIMIT` block constant defined in the eip

https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225